# Deployment Error Says Report Folder is Missing

Tags: deployment, salesforcedx-cli, xml, reports-folder

I'm deploying an sfdx project from VSCode. I'm getting errors on all of my report files that say "Cannot find folder:StoryNavigator." The folder and reports are in my package, so I'm not sure what's going on. Images below.

My command was working the last time I deployed the package to a scratch org. I just pulled down a bunch of changes from the org I was working in and now I can't deploy it to a new scratch org. There weren't any changes to the report folder file.

```
sfdx project deploy start -o username
```

I manually created the folder in the new scratch org and the deployment worked, but I still need to figure out what's going wrong.

[image: Folders]

[image: Errors]

Comment: How are you doing this deployment? Is it clicking on the project folder at the root? A specific folder below? Through the command line?

Comment: @RenatoOliveira I'm using the command line - sfdx project deploy start -o username

Comment: Could you add the exact command to your original post? That might provide relevant information to assist you. The command might not be specifying the folder, for example.

Comment: @RenatoOliveira Updated

Comment: Did you try the old command with `sfdx force source deploy` specifying the folder metadata in a separate fashion? With that working, your deploy command should also work (because then the folder will exist in the org).

Comment: I will try specifying the folder in another scratch org, thanks. The odd thing is that I created a managed package for the project, and when I install it via URL in another new org, I didn't get the report folder error.

Comment: @RochelleC I'm facing the same issue. Did you figure out how to resolve?

Comment: @TylerZika Sadly, no. It worked in a new package, so I might have just messed up my xml somehow.